# Communication from Web based Application to Desktop based Application

Tags: java, spring, desktop-application, rmi

i am working on an application which consist of two part one web based and other is desktop application, web based application will make a call to desktop based application both machine are in local area network. Application are written in Java. Somebody has advice me to use RMI. Where Web based application will act like RMIClient and desktop application will be RMIServer. for web based application we are using Spring Framework spring provied its own way for RMI Service which internally use java RMI. i have decided to do prototyping based on this Pattern.

Now i have created RMIClient using Spring please see code below :-

```
package com.rmi.client;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
@Controller
public class MainController {

@RequestMapping("/callrmiserver")
public void callRMISever(){
    ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ServiceBean.xml");
    System.out.print("before getbean");
    Hello hello = (Hello) ctx.getBean("helloService");
    System.out.print("i am greeting from "+hello.greeting());
   }

 }
```

ServiceBean.xml file is like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="Helloservice" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceUrl" value="rmi://localhost:1009/Services" />
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.rmi.client.Hello" />
</bean>
```

interface is like :

```
package com.rmi.client;

public interface Hello {
  String greeting();
}
```

Desktop based RMIServer is like

```
package rmiapplication;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
public class RMIServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException,  MalformedURLException {
       System.out.println("server conf...");
               LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1009);
               Hello hello = new HelloImpl();
               Naming.rebind("Services", hello);
               System.out.println("server.RMI Server is ready.");
        }

  }
```

Implementation Part of Method is :-

```
package rmiapplication;
```

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class HelloImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Hello{

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 6789759288861838122L;

public HelloImpl() throws RemoteException {
    }

    public String greeting() throws RemoteException {
        System.out.print("i am at server side call");
        return "greeting";
    }

    }
```

When i am running is whole setup, starting with rmiregistry, RMIServer and then webbased application i am getting java.rmi.NotBoundException here is full stack trace:-

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [rmi] in context with path [/SpringRMIClient] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.rmi.client.RMIService#0' defined in class path resource [ServiceBean.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'Helloservice' while setting bean property 'Helloservice'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'Helloservice' defined in class path resource [ServiceBean.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.remoting.RemoteLookupFailureException: Could not find RMI service [rmi://localhost:1009/Services] in RMI registry; nested exception is        java.rmi.NotBoundException: Services] with root cause
    java.rmi.NotBoundException: Services
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.lookup(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiClientInterceptor.lookupStub(RmiClientInterceptor.java:200)
at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiClientInterceptor.prepare(RmiClientInterceptor.java:147)
at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiClientInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet(RmiClientInterceptor.java:135)
at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiProxyFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(RmiProxyFactoryBean.java:68)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1469)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1409)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1317)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1076)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:872)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at com.rmi.client.MainController.callRMISever(MainController.java:13)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:175)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:421)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:409)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:774)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve.invoke(ReplicationValve.java:333)
at org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve.invoke(JvmRouteBinderValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:279)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Now i am not sure what is getting wrong in this i have tried google but didn't got any success now i have two Question based on this

1. How to remove above exception, i have also tried with different machine in LAN
2. What us best way to trigger Desktop Application from Web based application, so that it start its execution. Complete problem statement is we have compiler that run on Web based application and that complied code run on Local machine

Thank you,

I Got the solution, if someone is facing any problem related to Spring Web application and non-spring desktop application communication using RMI mail me

Thank you for community support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found out there is some situation where spring server and non spring client create problem  over rmi. but this is possible when you are using non spring server and spring client (Web Server to desktop application). in my case there was problem while using

here is my client

```
public void getRMIServer(){
    Registry registry = null;
    Hello stub;
    try {
        System.out.println("IN RMI CLients");
        registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost");
        stub = (Hello) registry.lookup("yash");
        System.out.println(stub.greeting());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is my server

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
        System.out.println("RMI Server Started");
        HelloImpl hello = new HelloImpl();
        UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(hello, true);
        Hello stub = (Hello) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(hello, 0);
        Registry reg = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1098);
        reg.rebind("yash", stub);
        System.out.println("server.RMI Server is ready.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

we also required shared resource that will reside on both server and client which is nothing but common interface

```
package shared;
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.Map;
  public interface Start extends Remote{
  public void startRMI(Map<Object,Object> m) throws RemoteException;
  public void stopRMI() throws RemoteException;
}
```

shared resource is interface that extends Remote Interface

if someone required working solution please let me know